# How to return error from Meteor.methods function

Tags: meteor

how to return error from Meteor.methods function?
I call my function:

```
Meteor.call('checkCode', mycode, function(error,result){
    console.log(result['name']);
  })
```

And it returns me name of person whose "code" is the same as argument.
But how return an error if there is nobody with input code?
My function code:

```
checkCode: function(zcode){
    return Codes.findOne({code: zcode});
  }
```

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `throw` as you would any normal javascript error. Meteor picks it up and returns the error to the client.

```
var code = Codes.findOne({code: zcode});

if(!code) 
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Error 500: Not found', 'the document is not found');

return code;
```